# Connecting TF CLC to on-premise TFS 2017

Tags: tfs, command-line, ssl-certificate

I try connecting to a TF Server 2017 with the actual build of TEE-CLC (version 14.134.0).
When issuing the command

```
./tf workfold "$/Collection" "/home/user/TFS/Collection" -map -login:username,password -server:"https://*ip-address*/tfs" -workspace:"WorkspaceName"
```

I get prompted that there is no workspace "WorkspaceName" to be found. I then proceeded to create a new Workspace with the following command:

```
./tf workspace -new -collection:"https://*ip-address*/tfs/DefaultCollection"
```

TF asks for my username and password, which I provide, then continues to throw an exection because it cannot validate the servers self-signed SSL certificate:

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Now I am just searching for a way to tell the TEE-CLC to accept untrusted certificates. I found some solutions while searching on Google, but none of them seem to work in the actual TEE-CLC version.

One solution suggested to edit the profile options of the client (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f11ea086-be44-4fa2-8e4e-ca8c6c92a8d8/im-receiving-the-error-quotunable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-targetquot-when?forum=tee), but the entire "profile" command is not available in the version I am using (anymore?).

Is there a way to tell TEE-CLC to accept untrusted certificates?

Comment: The correct solution here is to get a valid cert installed on your server.

Comment: The certificate is valid, it's just a domain certificate that is not signed by a well known CA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up importing the CA certifiacte to javas keystore:

```
sudo keytool -importcert -alias CA_NAME -cacerts -keystore $java_home/lib/security/cacerts -file path/to/ca.cer
```

The default password for openjdk's keystore is "changeit". After that I proceeded to create workspaces and map them accordingly to my local folder:

```
tf workfold "$/ProjectName" /path/to/local/folder/ProjectName -workspace:"hostname;username" -map
```

Comment: On my machine, the $java_home variable doesn't exist.  I can't seem to figure out where the default keystore is that tf is using